# Is there a way to avoid repetitive hook calls when we use components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've created a modal component hook below, but I am having problem.

My desire is to place this modal at the app level so that I can call it through a global state like Zustand whenever I need it.

And the structure of the modal component looks like this:

Create basic component of Modal

```
// components\shadcnui\modal.tsx
<Dialog open={isOpen} onOpenChange={onChange}>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>{title}</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>{description}</DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
        {children}
        <DialogFooter>{footer}</DialogFooter>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
```

```
 // zustand state management
export const useModal = create<UseModalType>(set => ({
  isOpen: false,
  title: '',
  description: '',
  children: <div />,
  labels: { cancel: '', confirm: '' },
  onActionButtonA: () => set({ isOpen: false }),
  onActionButtonB: () => set({ isOpen: false }),
  onOpen: ({
    title,
    labels,
    description,
    footer,
    onActionButtonA,
    onActionButtonB,
    children,
  }) => {
    if (title) {
      set({ title });
    }
    if (labels) {
      set({ labels });
    }
    if (description) {
      set({ description });
    }
    if (children) {
      set({ children });
    }
    if (footer) {
      set({ footer });
    }
    if (onActionButtonA) {
      set({ onActionButtonA });
    }
    if (onActionButtonB) {
      set({ onActionButtonB });
    }

    set({
      isOpen: true,
    });
  },
  onClose: () => set({ isOpen: false }),
}));
```

```
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  // get the current user
  // this is usefull when we want to see current user inside the navbar
  const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <ColorSchemeScript />
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className}>
          <ModalComponent/>
          {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

However, I feel like this is not efficient because to call it, I have to do two things. First, I have to call the hook, and then after calling the hook, I can execute the hook function.

```
const storeModal = useModal(); // ==>>> I REALLY HATE THIS LINE.. 

storeModal.onOpen({
        title: 'Please confirm your action',
        description: 'Are you sure you want to delete this Image?',
        labels: { cancel: 'Cancel', confirm: 'Confirm' },
        onActionButtonB: () => {
          const result = props.value.filter(data => data.name !== name);
          props.onChange(result);
          toast.success('Success deleted the image');
        },
      });
```

My expectation, i dont want to call `useModal()` whenever i use this. I'm inspired by Mantine, where they can do it like this: how do they achieve this without using hooks?

```
import { Button, Text } from '@mantine/core';
import { modals } from '@mantine/modals';

function Demo() {
  const openModal = () => modals.openConfirmModal({
    title: 'Please confirm your action',
    children: (
      <Text size="sm">
        This action is so important that you are required to confirm it with a modal. Please click
        one of these buttons to proceed.
      </Text>
    ),
    labels: { confirm: 'Confirm', cancel: 'Cancel' },
    onCancel: () => console.log('Cancel'),
    onConfirm: () => console.log('Confirmed'),
  });

  return <Button onClick={openModal}>Open confirm modal</Button>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use a global event bus, which is observed by the `ModalProvider` component. When you call `modals.openConfirmModal`, you basically emit an event, which is then noticed by the provider and consumed. As a result an action is passed to a reducer and React schedules rendering. That's basically it. Your modal will be rendered, because it's now stored in the internal state of this component.
You can read the source code [here](https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine/tree/master/packages/%40mantine/modals/src). Pay attention to `events.ts` and `ModalsProvider.ts`.

If you want to achieve similar thing with `zustand`, then I suggest creating a vanilla store.

```js
import { createStore } from 'zustand/vanilla'

const store = createStore((set) => ...)
```

It's not a good practice to expose your whole store to the public, so let's create a function, which will serve as a public API. It should save information passed as a parameter in the store, so we can access it later and render a component with correct content.

```js
export const openModal(modal: ModalOptions): void {
  store.setModal(modal);
}
```

Alright, we now have a way to 'open modal' from anywhere, but it's not shown yet. We need to bind our store with `ModalProvider` component.

```js
import { useStore } from 'zustand'
import { store } from './store'

export const ModalProvider = () => {
  const modal = useStore(store, (state) => state.modal);

  if (!modal) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Modal ... />
  );
}
```

Starting from now, our `ModalProvider` will render whenever `modal` changes in the store.

Voila, it should work perfectly now. Keep in mind, it's only a pseudo-code and you need to provide correct implementation yourself, but it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you for your best answer!!!

Previously, I had already implemented this in my code, but I completely forgot. Now I know how to do it. Big thanks!!